# Markdown : internal link to section doesn't work

Tags: markdown

This works :

```
See [java](#java) configuration
..
### Java
```

This doesn't work :

```
See [web.xml](#web-app-web.xml) configuration
..
### Web app web.xml
```

so why ? :)

Comment: But both ways are working in my case..

Comment: argh .. maybe a gitlab issue, this concerns a README.md with gitlab 11.2.5

Comment: this works : (#web-app-webxml)  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented in their [github/markup](https://github.com/github/markup) project, GitHub runs all user supplied markup through various filters, including the [TableOfContentsFilter](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/toc_filter.rb). The filter isn't fully documented, but a quick read through the code suggests that to create an `id`, the text of a header is filtered by having...

1. all characters converted to lowercase ASCII characters;
2. all punctuation (except hyphens and spaces) removed; and
3. all spaces replaced with hyphens.

Running the text `Web app web.xml` through such a filter will result in `web-app-webxml`. That being the case, your document should look like this:

```
See [web.xml](#web-app-webxml) configuration
..
### Web app web.xml
```

Comment: If this answers the question, then you can accept the answer. If it was helpful, you can upvote the answer.